# Jboss as a service failing on OS Reboot RHEL8

Tags: linux, selinux, jboss, systemctl, rhel8

0

I am facing some issues while running Jboss as a service on RHEL8 servers. The setup of service is done in a standard way as per the RHEL guidelines

[https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/installation_guide/configuring_jboss_eap_to_run_as_a_service.](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/installation_guide/configuring_jboss_eap_to_run_as_a_service)

The issue is that manual start/stop using systemctl command works fine. but it fails to automatically start up Jboss service in case of OS reboot with below error

```
[ec2-user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ sudo systemctl status jboss-eap-rhel
● jboss-eap-rhel.service - SYSV: JBoss EAP startup script
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/jboss-eap-rhel.sh; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Tue 2022-10-18 02:09:10 UTC; 5min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 753 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/jboss-eap-rhel.sh start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 18 02:06:50 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: JBoss EAP startup script...
Oct 18 02:06:50 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.internal runuser[777]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user jboss by (uid=0)
Oct 18 02:06:50 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.internal runuser[777]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user jboss
Oct 18 02:06:50 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.internal jboss-eap-rhel.sh[753]: Starting jboss-eap: /
Oct 18 02:09:10 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.internal jboss-eap-rhel.sh[753]: jboss-eap started with errors, please see server log for details
Oct 18 02:09:10 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.internal jboss-eap-rhel.sh[753]: [  OK  ]
Oct 18 02:09:10 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: jboss-eap-rhel.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/jboss-eap/jboss-eap.pid (yet?) >
Oct 18 02:09:10 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: jboss-eap-rhel.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Oct 18 02:09:10 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: JBoss EAP startup script.
```

Nothing much is getting logged in the host-controller logs as well even with detailed logging, with the process suddenly exiting with status code 99

```
2022-10-18 02:08:48,512 DEBUG [org.jboss.modules] (main) Module org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-validator-provider defined by local module loader @65e2dbf3 (finder: local module finder @4f970963 (roots: /space/jboss/jboss-eap-7.4/modules,/space/jboss/jboss-eap-7.4/modules/system/layers/base/.overlays/layer-base-jboss-eap-7.4.4.CP,/space/jboss/jboss-eap-7.4/modules/system/layers/base))
2022-10-18 02:08:48,913 DEBUG [org.jboss.logging] (main) Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.JBossLogManagerProvider
2022-10-18 02:08:49,042 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (main) WFLYSRV0239: Aborting with exit code 99
```

While troubleshooting there were quite a few posts pointing that this could be a issue of SELinux denying permissions. Tried the scenario with SELinux permissive/disabled but the problem still persists. There is no additional information available in systemd logs as well. Can anybody help me with the above. I am not able to figure out how to proceed further. Thanks

Comment: Have you found following question and answer here? It helped me when facing the same issue: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=1765077